# issues moving existing github repos into new folder

Tags: github

I'm trying to take the 15 repos I currently have on github and end up with one main folder title 'web_fundamentals' that they are all in and then maybe a sub folder or 2 in that (example: intro_oop_python).

What I have been trying based off answers on how to do this is.

1. go to settings of repo I want to put inside main directory
2. click "rename" then add: "main_folder/" in front of the existing name.
3. I would assume go to other repos and use the same "main_folder/" and then they should all be there.

[But after I do this (see image bellow) I don't see a new directory it merely changes the name of that repo to "main_folder-oop_projects"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ariyb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot reorganize repos on GitHub itself: there are listed under your account, not under folders or subfolders.

You might consider reference them in a [GitHub organization](https://help.github.com/articles/about-organizations/): that would be one level only, no "sub-folders".

Or you could also consider making one parent repo `web_fundamentals`, in which you [reference your other repos as submodules](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) (see "[Git Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)").
The advantage is that you can add those other repos in any path you want, with folders/subfolders named as you want (as part of that submodule path)

Comment: Thanks VonC, "Git Submodules" is exactly what I needed!